# Mocking fails() and make() on a Validator object

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5, mockery

I am trying to mock the response I get from a `Validator` object using `Mockery`, I am trying eventually for force a pass or a fail on the validation so that I can test what happens after the validation. I have tried the following with no joy.

```
$validator = Validator::shouldReceive('make')
    ->once()
    ->with([], $this->rules);

$validator->shouldReceive('fails')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(true);
```

And

```
$validator = Validator::shouldReceive('make')
    ->once()
    ->with([], $this->rules)
    ->shouldReceive('fails')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(true);
```

With both of these I then set the validator property in the class to the object coming back from Mockery

The function I am trying to test looks like this

```
class JsonModel extends Model
{

    private $validator;

    public function createFromJSON(array $inputData, $throwException = false)
    {
        // This calls Validator::make
        $this->makeValidator(
            $inputData, 
            $this->getValidationRules() // An internal function that returns the rules for the Model
        );

        if($this->validator->fails()) {
             if($throwException === true) {
                 throw new Exception('Validation failed');
             } else {
                 return null;
             }
         }
        return null;

        /** @var Model $model */
        $model = self::create($inputData);
        return $model;
    }

    private function makeValidator($inputData, $ruleData)
    {
        $this->validator = Validator::make($inputData, $ruleData);
    }
}
```

I'm open to suggestions for other approaches, not essential that I fix it because I can just go down the return null path, remove the exception and assume Validator will do it's job but it's bugging me.

Comment: Can we see `makeValidator` please? You lose me with "With both of these I then set the validator property in the class to the object coming back from Mockery"

Comment: I don't understand how you're creating the mocks: $validator = Validator::shouldReceive('make')

Comment: @gontrollez - This I picked up from the Laravel 5 documentaton that this was how to mock a validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer after much tinkering. It's all to do with the way that you call the validator. I decided to change the function so that all that it does is validate the object using the rules set. So I'm now returning the result of `passes()` instead of `fails()`. For anyone else trying to mock this the below should help you.

```
public function testWithMockValidator()
{
    // Mock the function you wish to mock and the result
    $mockValidator = \Mockery::mock('\Illuminate\Validation\Validator');
    $mockValidator->shouldReceive('passes')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(false);

    // Then Mock the factory that will be used to create the validator
    $factory = '\Illuminate\Validation\Factory';

    $mockFactory = \Mockery::mock($factory);
    $mockFactory->shouldReceive('make')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($mockValidator);

    // Register the mock with the app
    \App::instance($factory, $mockFactory);

    // Create the object I need
    $obj = \Mockery::mock(self::CLASS_NAME)->makePartial();

    // Set a property using reflection
    $property = UTH::i()->makePropertyAccessible(
        self::CLASS_NAME,
        self::PROP_VALIDATION_RULES
    );
    $property->setValue($obj, $this->rules);

    // call my function (which has been renamed and redesigned to just validate the model
    $return = $obj->validate(['foo' => true]);

    // $return will be whatever you set it to in the mock above
    $this->assertFalse($return);
}
```

Here is the function in the class being tested

```
public final function validate(array $inputData)
{
    $factory = \App::make('\Illuminate\Validation\Factory');
    // This retrieves the private property
    $rules = $this->getValidationRules();

    $this->validator = $factory->make($inputData, $rules);

    return $this->validator->passes();
}
```